# PHP data("I") is showing 0 for "America/Phoenix" timezone

Tags: php, timezone

I want the know whether this timezone is on Day light saving
I've used the following code

```
 $userTimezone = new DateTimeZone("America/Phoenix");

 $datObj = new DateTime(date('Y-M-d H:i:s'),$userTimezone);

 $dls = $datObj->format('I');
```

The value of `$dls` is 0 , but this timezone is actually on day light saving
The following time zones are working fine for me

```
America/Chicago
America/New_York
America/Los_Angeles
```

Can any one help me to resolve this ?

Comment: According to [this](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/phoenix), `America/Phoenix` does not have daytime saving (anymore)

Comment: If you're looking for US Mountain Time that *does* use DST, use `America/Denver` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The America/Phoenix time zone has not observed daylight saving time since 1967. Here are the rules from [IANA 2019c](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/e733957e6e77e184c6d2ff017960dfd76deedd7f/northamerica#L820):

```
# Zone  NAME        STDOFF  RULES   FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone America/Phoenix    -7:28:18 -  LMT 1883 Nov 18 11:31:42
            -7:00   US  M%sT    1944 Jan  1  0:01
            -7:00   -   MST 1944 Apr  1  0:01
            -7:00   US  M%sT    1944 Oct  1  0:01
            -7:00   -   MST 1967
            -7:00   US  M%sT    1968 Mar 21
            -7:00   -   MST
```

So the only rule that's still in force is the last one, putting the time zone in MST.